# Multi level dependent drop down list in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a multi level dependent list using excel. I have three columns CODE, STATE and CITY. The sample data as below.

[image]

The data have 18k CODE.

As of now, below the steps I have performed.

1. I have created a list of CODE using validation in cell G5.
2. I have selected CODE column range and created Name Manager 'Codes'.
3. In a next cell I have created a list and inside source I have put a formula `=OFFSET($B$2,MATCH(G5,Codes,0)-1,,COUNTIF(Codes,G5))`. This way I get the state depends on the CODE.
4. I have created Name Manager for state column
5. Now, to get the CITY, in the next column, I have created a list and inside source I have put a formula `=OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(1,(F2=CODE)*(G2=STATE),0),0,COUNTIF(G2,STATE))`

It is not giving me the expected result.

I am expecting, depending on the CODE and STATE a corresponding CITY list gets populated.

Requesting your assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by multilevel dropdown list? A dropdown where you first select `Code`, then `State` within `Code` and then `City`?

Comment: In this complex case a sample file is helpful. Can you just share a sample workbook here over google drive or dropbox link?

Comment: @VBAPete, yes. A dropdown where I will select CODE then STATE within CODE and then it's CITY

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem using two array formulas:

In cell H5 (and copied down):

> {=IFERROR(INDEX(State, MATCH(0, IF($G$5=Codes, COUNTIF($H$4:$H4, State), ""), 0)),"")}

In cell I5 (and copied down):

> {=IFERROR(INDEX(City, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($J$4:J4,City)+(State<>$I$5)+(Codes<>$G$5), 0)),"")}

where:

- `Codes` is `range(A2:A12)`
- `State` is `range(B2:B12)`
- `City` is `range(C2:C12)`
- `G5` is the cell for the city criteria
- `I5` is the cell for the state criteria

[image]

[image]

Array formulas and must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. You cannot enter the {...} brackets manually.